# How to convert ObservableCollection property result in to ObservableCollection type

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I have the following read only property,which I need to set it to below mentioned linq expression inside get statement. I have no idea how to do this.
Any advice or guidance will be much appreciated!

```
public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Author>();
```

linq query

```
var result = (from author in Authors where author.Name.StartsWith(this.filterText) select author).ToList<Author>();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: You can pass it to `ObservableCollection` constructor

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = this.Authors.Where(author => author.Name.StartsWith(this.filterText));
var filteredAuthors = new ObservableCollection<Authors>(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ObservableCollection<Author> Authors
{
   get
   {
     var result = (from author in Authors
                   where author.Name.StartsWith(this.filterText) 
                   select author).ToList();
     return new ObservableCollection<Author>(result);
   }
}
```

> Blockquote